# python-oracledb thin client incorrect database timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, cx-oracle, python-oracledb

When I use thin client **python-oracledb** to get data from tables, which contains datetime columns with timestamp as "2022-10-15 14:35:09.000000 +00:00" I receive wrong timestamp like this "2022-10-12 17:39:09", time difference of 3 days and 4 minutes. But when I use **cx_oracle** version 8.3.0 I get correct timestamp from same table and same column.

python-oracledb vesion: **1.2.2**

cx_oracle version: **8.3.0**

oracle database version: **19.14.0.0.0**

```py
conn: Connection = oracledb.connect(user=user1,
                                    password=password1,
                                    dsn=connection1,
                                    encoding=codepage1)

conn_cx_ora = cx_Oracle.connect(user=user1,
                                password=password1,
                                dsn=connection1,
                                encoding=codepage1)

try:
    cursor: Cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    rows1 = cursor.fetchall()
    mig_start1: datetime = rows1[1][1]

    cursor: Cursor = conn_cx_ora.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    rows_cx = cursor.fetchall()
    mig_start_cx: datetime = rows_cx[1][1]
finally:
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    conn_cx_ora.close()

print(rows1)
print(rows_cx)
```

output:

```
[datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 12, 8, 2, 43)]
[datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 15, 4, 58, 33]
```

I need understand, why python-oracledb receive wrong datetime.

Comment: What are: session time zone, client time zone, database time zone? What is the **real type** of column (check in `user_tab_cols` database dictionary view)? Is it `timestamp` or `timestamp with time zone` or maybe `timestamp with local time zone`?

Comment: This question is being followed up on at https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/discussions/131

Comment: real type of column timestamp(6)_with_timezone